# Google drive - how to create a file inside the same folder

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api

I've created a new folder "Folder_Name" and put the generated csv file inside the folder. When i click the upload csv button this method is called. It creates the folder and then create the file inside the folder.

How ever when i click the button again it creates a new folder again and new file inside it. How can i create and use one unique folders and put the file inside the folder when ever this method is called.

Code:

```
- (void)uploadGeneratedCSVFile
{
    [ self generateCSV ];  
    NSString* filePath = [ [self applicationDocumentsDirectory ] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName ];
    NSString* mimeType = @"text/csv";

    GTLDriveFile* folder = [ GTLDriveFile object ];
    [ folder setTitle:@"Folder_Name" ];
    [ folder setMimeType:@"application/vnd.google-apps.folder" ];
    GTLUploadParameters* folderUploadParameters = [ GTLUploadParameters new ];
    GTLQueryDrive* queryFolder = [ GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:folder uploadParameters:nil ];
    [ self.driveService executeQuery:queryFolder completionHandler:^( GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                                 GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                                 NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil)
    {
        NSLog( @"Created Folder" );
        GTLDriveParentReference* parent = [ GTLDriveParentReference object ];
        [ parent setIdentifier:updatedFile.identifier ];

        // Metadata
        GTLDriveFile* file = [ GTLDriveFile object ];
        [ file setTitle:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@",fileName, currDateStr ] ];
        [ file setParents:[ NSArray arrayWithObjects:parent, nil ] ];

        GTLUploadParameters* uploadParameters = [ GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:csv MIMEType:mimeType];
        GTLQueryDrive* query = [ GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:file uploadParameters:uploadParameters ];
        [ self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^( GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                                   GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                                   NSError *error)
         {
             if (error == nil)
             {
                 NSLog(@"File %@", updatedFile.originalFilename);
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
             }

             [ self viewDidAppear:YES ];
         }];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog( @"An error occurred: %@",error );
    }
}];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that Google Drive Files (and Folders - which are just files anyway) are identified by a unique ID, and NOT by their name. So if you tell Drive to create a second folder with the same name as a previous folder, Drive assumes you know what you're doing and obeys. What you need to do is capture the ID of the folder the first time around, and then use that ID as the parent for subsequent inserts.

Comment: i think am getting grasp of it. So if i want to access files inside folder I need to query GTLDriveFile by setting parent ID and in completion handler i get the file ids.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Objective C class names, but it sounds correct.